# Calculate Last Working Day of the Previous Month

Tags: excel, vba

Hi All can you please help me with a VBA code for Last Working Day, which excludes the weekends only, of the Previous Month?

The one I tried below is giving me only the Last date without the working day.

```
Range("B8") = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now, -1)
```

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-workday-function

Comment: Use the [WorksheetFunction.WorkDay method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.workday)

Comment: @Andreas: The holidays-parameter is optional.

Comment: @Andreas Well then don't specify any holidays as third argument and it only detects weekends.

Comment: my bad! I thought it was built in.

Comment: @Andreas well therefore it would need to know where exactly you live ^^ Every country, state, city has different holidays.

Comment: It knows my timezone and decimal settings and such using the regional settings. It wouldn't surprise me if it would know/guess that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim dt As Date, dt_LastMonth As Date, dt_LastWorkingDate_LastMonth As Date
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    dt = Now
    dt_LastMonth = DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt) - 1, 1)
    dt_LastWorkingDate_LastMonth = wf.WorkDay(wf.EoMonth(dt_LastMonth, 0) + 1, -1)
    MsgBox dt_LastWorkingDate_LastMonth
End Sub
```

If today is a day in May 2021, the code produces:

[image]

Comment: This code worked for me

ActiveSheet.Range("F3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1) + 1, -1)

Comment: Yes that's what i wanted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to return the last workday of the previous month.

```
Private Function LastWorkday() As Date

    Dim Fun     As Date             ' function return value
    
    Fun = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)
    Do
        If (Weekday(Fun) < vbSaturday) And _
           (Weekday(Fun) > vbSunday) Then Exit Do
        Fun = Fun - 1
    Loop
    LastWorkday = Fun
    
    Debug.Print Format(Fun, "ddd, d mmm yyyy")
End Function
```